# Timeout setValueAsync from Docker with Firebase Real Time Database

Tags: firebase, docker, firebase-realtime-database

I'm implementing Firebase with Admin SDK with Docker, and in my local spring project it works. I can insert data to my database. The problem happens when I put my project inside a Docker, where I cant insert in firebase, I feel like it is a timeout for something. I give a code example of the functionality:

```
String path = String.format(formatPath, mqTicket.getOperatorCompanyId(), mqTicket.getParkingLocationId(),
        mqTicket.getTicket());
try {
    LOGGER.info(path);
    DatabaseReference ticketReference = database.getReference(path);
    Ticket ticket = new Ticket(mqTicket.getTicket(), mqTicket.getEmployee(), mqTicket.getStatus(),
            mqTicket.getTime().format(isoFormatter));
    ApiFuture<Void> apiFuture = ticketReference.setValueAsync(ticket);
    ticketReference.push().setValueAsync(ticket);
    apiFuture.get();
    LOGGER.info(ticket.toString());
} catch (DatabaseException e) {
    LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error("Error unexpected in MQ server");
    LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone came with the same problem PROBABLY they had the same issue in your server. For me it was because the time it was not correct. I detected it because the UTC it was different by 8 minutes. I saw the utc time of the server with:

```
date -u
```

I compared the time with the time google gave me in UTC and there I saw the problem.
I change it with:

```
sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
```

To detect the problem I used in the spring project in the properties the next line:

```
logging.level.root=TRACE
```

And reading the log, in the POST error of google gave the hint:

```
Check your iat and exp values and use a clock with skew to account for clock differences between systems
```

It because they deal with the tokens and expiration time internally. No other configuration beside time it was done. so take time to review this issue.